# Connecting to Firebird database in BIML

Tags: sql, ssis, firebird, biml, firebird-.net-provider

I am trying to connect to Firebird database using BIML script, but I'm getting errors about not supported keywords like "DataSource". When I change them to "Data Source" it is supported, but then BIML tries to connect to Firebird database via sqlserver, which results in Named Pipes Provider, error: 40. My original .dtsx packages have Firebird Provider adonet connections configurated and are working as they should.

Is there any way I can connect to firebird in BIML or disable validation completely when generating a .dtsx package? DelayingValidation only delays it unfortunately.

My connection string in BIML:

```
<AdoNetConnection Name="FB" ConnectionString="user id=<user>;password=<password>;database=<databasefile>;DataSource=<server>;pooling=True;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=30;enlist=False;connection lifetime=30;connection timeout=30;" RetainSameConnection="true" Provider="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, Version=6.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<token>" />
```

Comment: If you use the free [BimlExpress](https://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress) add-on (or BimlStudio) you can reverse engineer existing SSIS packages into Biml. Does the reverse engineered package use the same connection string?

Comment: Your aside about `DataSource` vs `Data Source` is niggling at my brain. Your provided connection strings doesn't really look like the samples over on [connectionstrings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/) When you switched to Data Source and indicate it's trying to connect to SQL Server, that smells a lot like either the provider information is wrong (third half of the connection string) or the non-standard key/values in the first section are causing the biml engine to get confused and default to assuming SQL Server protocol

Comment: Yes, however the biml also doesn't recognize the connection string provided by you (DataSource is not supported it says). The connection string provided by me is the connection string used in .dtsx package and it works as it should, I can execute queries on Firebird database. I fear biml doesn't support firebird and I want to know if there's any workaround. If not then tough luck I think